# Strange spacing in multi-line ZPL label formats

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am working on a Windows tablet application that generates ZPL label formats from a database and send them to a ZQ520 printer over a Generic/Text printer driver. Generating the ZPL format and sending it to the printer works like a charm. I am running into an issue where the multiline text in either Table Block, Field Blocks or simply Field Data tags has extraneous spaces between several words. Even after changing the font for the fields, I still get the same spacing between the same words. I have examined the text of the ZPL file in a hexadecimal editor and there are no extraneous characters in the fields, the placement seems to be random in that there is no common combination of characters triggering the extraneous spaces.

One of the attempts I have made to try to narrow the problem down is:

```
^XA
^LL800
^LH15,15
^FO15,0
^A022,22
^TBN,752,250^FDLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin porttitor porta urna sed pharetra. Quisque at malesuada dolor. Cras mollis justo neque, quis commodo arcu condimentum molestie. Ut elit justo, tempus vitae nulla sed, rutrum fringilla dui. Proin scelerisque nisi pretium arcu tristique, eu mollis ante fermentum. Ut eu imperdiet sem. Proin ultricies sit amet sem sodales fermentum. Morbi vehicula elementum tempor. Suspendisse ut ligula ac nunc aliquam consectetur. Nullam nec scelerisque ante. Nam sodales justo at velit vestibulum, non dignissim risus feugiat. Morbi consectetur sit amet ligula ut dictum. Quisque efficitur, lorem vel ullamcorper blandit, magna nibh sodales metus, non egestas felis erat pretium justo. Aliquam pulvinar ex eget condimentum suscipit. Pellentesque sed ornare nibh. Nunc commodo ullamcorper tincidunt.^FS
^XZ
```

The spaces appear between adipiscing and elit, malesuada and dolor, condimentum and molestie, dui. and Proin and many others. I have also tried using fonts C, D, F and 0 (zero). Additionally, I have also used the ZPL and the CPCL Zebra printer drivers as well as the Seagull Scientific driver with the same results on both a Windows tablet and a Windows PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been solved. I was printing from Notepad with margins and a header and footer set. By removing those setting in the print setup, and printing to the generic text driver.

Comment: Can confirm removing the Notepad margins fixes this! Not a setting on printer, but specifically notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Is your font Scale-able?
Also check your firmware on the printer itself, this sounds like it could be a text wrapping issue that would be handled in the Printer.

[Link to Label](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5ELL800%0A%5ELH15%2C15%0A%5EFO15%2C0%0A%5EA022%2C22%0A%5ETBN%2C752%2C250%5EFDLorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%2C%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit.%20Proin%20porttitor%20porta%20urna%20sed%20pharetra.%20Quisque%20at%20malesuada%20dolor.%20Cras%20mollis%20justo%20neque%2C%20quis%20commodo%20arcu%20condimentum%20molestie.%20Ut%20elit%20justo%2C%20tempus%20vitae%20nulla%20sed%2C%20rutrum%20fringilla%20dui.%20Proin%20scelerisque%20nisi%20pretium%20arcu%20tristique%2C%20eu%20mollis%20ante%20fermentum.%20Ut%20eu%20imperdiet%20sem.%20Proin%20ultricies%20sit%20amet%20sem%20sodales%20fermentum.%20Morbi%20vehicula%20elementum%20tempor.%20Suspendisse%20ut%20ligula%20ac%20nunc%20aliquam%20consectetur.%20Nullam%20nec%20scelerisque%20ante.%20Nam%20sodales%20justo%20at%20velit%20vestibulum%2C%20non%20dignissim%20risus%20feugiat.%20Morbi%20consectetur%20sit%20amet%20ligula%20ut%20dictum.%20Quisque%20efficitur%2C%20lorem%20vel%20ullamcorper%20blandit%2C%20magna%20nibh%20sodales%20metus%2C%20non%20egestas%20felis%20erat%20pretium%20justo.%20Aliquam%20pulvinar%20ex%20eget%20condimentum%20suscipit.%20Pellentesque%20sed%20ornare%20nibh.%20Nunc%20commodo%20ullamcorper%20tincidunt.%5EFS%0A%5EXZ)

Comment: I am using the scalable font for this example, but I get the same results on bitmapped fonts as well. Also, I updated the firmware to the latest from Zebra and reset the printer to the Factory settings (^JUF, ^JUN and ^JUS to save). Zebra cannot reproduce this, so I'm suspecting we may have a bad unit for testing.

Comment: how are you communicating to the printer? if serial is there any chance of signal problems?

Comment: I am using a Generic/Text printer connected to a tablet via Bluetooth and a PC using USB. I can run any other script over the connections without any loss. It is just the wrapped text boxes, regardless of script that give me this error.